# Как загрузить URL в Jquery Dialog?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css, iframe

Способ через iframe знаю, но он мне не подходит.
Я хочу, что бы отображалась не вся страница, а только определенный div#id.

Хотя я думаю, что он всё равно сначала загрузит всю страницу, потом построить DOM, а только потом отфильтрует.

Есть ли какой-то оптимальный способ? Не обязательно Jquery Dialog (хотя если есть способ с этим, то очень буду рад). Главное, что бы можно было определенный блок с страницы загрузить и желательно только его, а не всю страницу.

Comment: > Я хочу, что бы отображалась не вся страница, а только определенный div#id.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document that is fetched:

    $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я уже нашёл ответ)